# Changing a part of name from a input field with jquery

Tags: jquery

I tried to add rows dynamically to a table. I have cloned the last added row. On every new row the name of the input field should rename with a number `+1`. For this, I wanted to rename the input fields, but I failed to do it in this way.

```
    Original row
    <input type="text" name="myfiels[0]" value="mytext">
First clone row
<input type="text" name="myfiels[1]" value="mytext">
Second clone row
<input type="text" name="myfiels[]" value="mytext">
...


$trNew.find('[name]').each(function () {
                    var num = this.name.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    if (!num) {num = 0;}

                    // Remove numbers by first regexp
                    // increment number
                    //this.name = this.name.replace(/\d/g, '') + (1 + parseInt(num, 10));

                    this.name.replace(/[.+]/,"["+(1 + parseInt(num, 10))+"]");                       
                });
```

I think the `regex` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some variable i.e : `count` which will hold next value to add in `name` and when you loop through each input you can get the name of `input` and replace it with new name ie : `name+"["+count+"]"` and then increment the count by `1`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var count = 0;//delcare this
$("div").find('input').each(function() {
var name = $(this).attr("name");//get name of input field
 $(this).attr("name", name +"[" + count + "]");//add new name
  count++;//increment

});

function namess() {
  $("div").find('input').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("name"));
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original row
<div>
  <input type="text" name="myfiels" value="mytext"> First clone row
  <input type="text" name="myfiels" value="mytext"> Second clone row
  <input type="text" name="myfiels" value="mytext"> ...
</div>
<button onclick="namess()">Click me to get names</button>
```